# Reshape vs. tidyr for repeated measures with multiple dependent variables

Tags: r, tidyr, melt

I have the following sample data of 10 cases with three repeated measures for two dependent variables "Rapport" and "STRS":

```
structure(list(SubID = structure(1:10, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
"71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
"82", "83", "84"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), Age = structure(c(5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "10", "11", "8", "9"
), class = "factor"), Rapport.1 = structure(c(22L, 25L, 19L, 
10L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 16L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "1.1", 
"1.85", "2.45", "2.5", "2.55", "2.6", "2.75", "2.8", "2.85", 
"2.9", "2.95", "3.2", "3.25", "3.3", "3.35", "3.4", "3.45", "3.5", 
"3.55", "3.6", "3.65", "3.7", "3.75", "3.8", "3.85", "3.9", "3.95"
), class = "factor"), Rapport.2 = structure(c(29L, 31L, 27L, 
17L, 9L, 26L, 24L, 21L, 30L, 32L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "1.25", 
"1.4", "1.6", "1.95", "2.05", "2.3", "2.35", "2.45", "2.5", "2.65", 
"2.7", "2.75", "2.8", "2.85", "3", "3.05", "3.1", "3.15", "3.2", 
"3.35", "3.4", "3.45", "3.5", "3.55", "3.6", "3.65", "3.7", "3.75", 
"3.8", "3.85", "3.9", "3.95", "4"), class = "factor"), Rapport.3 =     structure(c(32L, 
35L, 22L, 22L, 5L, 25L, 30L, 21L, 25L, 34L), .Label = c("#NULL!", 
"1.35", "1.45", "1.6", "1.75", "1.85", "1.9", "1.95", "2.05", 
"2.1", "2.25", "2.3", "2.35", "2.4", "2.45", "2.6", "2.75", "2.8", 
"2.9", "2.95", "3", "3.05", "3.1", "3.2", "3.25", "3.3", "3.35", 
"3.4", "3.45", "3.5", "3.55", "3.6", "3.7", "3.75", "3.8", "3.85"
), class = "factor"), STRS.1 = structure(c(33L, 10L, 8L, 18L, 
29L, 22L, 7L, 28L, 37L, 26L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "100", "102", 
"103", "104", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", 
"113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "122", 
"123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "132", "133", 
"69", "71", "73", "85", "88", "89", "92", "97", "99"), class = "factor"), 
STRS.2 = structure(c(37L, 19L, 9L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 16L, 16L, 
42L, 31L), .Label = c("#NULL!", "100", "101", "103", "104", 
"105", "106", "107", "108", "110", "111", "113", "114", "115", 
"116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", 
"125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "131", "132", "136", "137", 
"138", "139", "158", "63", "76", "80", "91", "94", "95", 
"98", "99"), class = "factor"), STRS.3 = structure(c(31L, 
11L, 19L, 23L, 22L, 13L, 17L, 17L, 34L, 29L), .Label = c("#NULL!", 
"102", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", 
"112", "114", "117", "118", "119", "120", "122", "123", "124", 
"125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", 
"134", "135", "66", "70", "75", "81", "85", "87", "88", "94", 
"98"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("SubID", "Gender", 
"Age", "Rapport.1", "Rapport.2", "Rapport.3", "STRS.1", "STRS.2", 
"STRS.3"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried to use the "melt" function in reshape and the "gather" function in tidyr but both produce one column with the variable names "Rapport" and "STRS" stacked and another column with their values. I haven't been able to figure out how to produce a single column for the "Rapport" values and another column for the "STRS" values so that I can use a random effects model (note:I left out the other demograpic variables and covariates). Any help with these two functions would be much appreciated.

```
teachermelt <- melt(TeacherW,
id.vars=c("SubID", "Gender","Age"), 
measure.vars=c("Rapport.1", "Rapport.2", "Rapport.3", "STRS.1","STRS.2","STRS.3" ),
variable.name="Rapport","STRS",
value.name="Rapport","STRS)

teachertidy <- gather(TeacherW, Rapport, STRS, Rapport.1:STRS.3)
```

I was finally able to obtain the longform using this "reshape" function, which seems quite simple but I'm not sure if there's anything I need to be aware of when doing it this way:

```
Teacherl<-reshape(TeacherW, varying = 4:9, sep = ".", idvar="SubID", direction = 'long')
View(Teacherl)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'ts difficult to be sure if this is what you want but here's a

Starting with `df`:

```
  SubID Gender Age Rapport.1 Rapport.2 Rapport.3 STRS.1 STRS.2 STRS.3
1     1      2   9      3.65      3.75       3.6     73     76     66
2     2      1  11       3.8      3.85       3.8    110    120    112
3     3      2  10       3.5      3.65      3.05    108    108    124
4     4      1  10      2.85      3.05      3.05    118    123    128
5     5      2  11      3.45      2.45      1.75    132    122    127
```

#### `Tidyr` sol'n:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
unite(one,contains("1")) %>%  # unite all columns that contain '1' with default sep = "_" into single new column named "one"
unite(two, contains("2")) %>% 
unite(three, contains("3")) %>% 
gather(replicate,values,one:three) %>%   # gather all columns between that named "one" and that named "three" (inclusive) into two new columns: a key column (named "replicate") and a value column (named "values")
separate(values,c("Rapport","STRS"),sep = "_") # separate the column named "values" into two new columns named "Rapport" and "STRS" according to the separator "_".
```

which gives:

```
   SubID Gender Age replicate Rapport STRS
1      1      2   9       one    3.65   73
2      2      1  11       one     3.8  110
3      3      2  10       one     3.5  108
4      4      1  10       one    2.85  118
5      5      2  11       one    3.45  132
6      1      2   9       two    3.75   76
7      2      1  11       two    3.85  120
8      3      2  10       two    3.65  108
9      4      1  10       two    3.05  123
10     5      2  11       two    2.45  122
11     1      2   9     three     3.6   66
12     2      1  11     three     3.8  112
13     3      2  10     three    3.05  124
14     4      1  10     three    3.05  128
15     5      2  11     three    1.75  127
```

#### explanation:

What you are asking for (*i think*) is to gather both `Rapport` and `STRS` cols but linked according to their nominations (`.1`,`.2`,`.3`). To tidy this up you:

- `unite()` the linked variables together into one column for each (forming varibles `one`, `two`, `three`). After this you can
- `gather()` these columns according to a key-value pair (here `replicate` and `values`). Lastly,
- `separate()` the `values` variable back into its constituent variables `Rapport` and `STRS`.

### N.B.

I think the appropriate "tidy" data structure here would be: (just to be safe)

```
df %>%
  gather(key, value, -SubID,-Gender,-Age) %>% 
  separate(key, into = c("var","idx"), sep="\\.")
```

Comment: Thank you but this is as far as I was able to get (maybe my own examples don't get that far because I've tinkered with them so much these might have addional errors) . I 'm hoping to be able to obtain two columns of values for both the "Rapport"  and "STRS"  variables so that a single subject would be on three rows with a measure for "Rapport"  and a corresponding measure for "STRS" on the same row. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @user3594490 can you post intended result in your question

Comment: I am reposting this question with a sample of the desired output and a smaller # of cases so it will be easier to follow. Same title with a "2". I don't know if this is ok to do.

Comment: Reposted "Reshape vs. tidyr for repeated measures with multiple dependent variables (2)" but not deleting this one because of everyone's responses.

Comment: @user3594490 I had a chance to re-read the questions and have re-posted an answer which I think should be helpful.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this achieves the longform I was trying to create. I hadn't seen the "unite" function before.  Do you happen to have any idea how I would obtain a similar result with the "melt" function?

Comment: The NB at the end seems the prefix to a better solution; adding a `%>% spread(var, value)` makes it almost exactly the same as the more complex unite/separate solution.